# How to create key array from nested JSON by particular value with lodash or without lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash, nested-loops

I want create key array which  value is "***str***" 
I have following nested json:

```
[
  {
    "Attr": [
      {
        "power": { "p1": "str", "t3": "str" },
        "light": [
          {"test": "str"},
          {"test2": [ { "t4": "str" }]}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Attr1": [
      {
        "power1": { "p2": "str", "t5": "str" },
        "light1": [
          { "test3": "str" },
          { "test_x": [
              { "t_x": "str" },
              { "t_y": [
                  { "t_y1": "str" }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to create array of key where key value is "***str***",

I want get following array output:

```
["p1", "t3", "test", "p2", "t5", "test3", "t_x", "t_y1"]
```

How to create key array from nested JSON by particular value?

Comment: Please post what you've tried. Have you made any attempt yet?

Comment: `{test2": [ { "t4` is invalid syntax.

Comment: Anyway, I believe that you need to show some effort first. I see a recursive reducing function here. Why don't you try to do it yourself and you come back with some specific question?

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, why do you have test2 in your expected output? test2 key doesn't have "str" as its value. :/

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer - Check my answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/51323540/5677020)  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can write an recursive function that would be best for performance.

But if you want to skip the recursive calling with (for each keys in a nested object), then you can try `JSON.parse` with additional parameter (callback) which will be called recursively by it. as a generic solution, I am adding a snippet (with `JSON.parse`, assuming helping on writing a recursive function should not be entertained / part of this answer).

But remember, IF you are bothered about performance efficiency you should not use this as you have to stringify (may be a large object) and again parse. But, if you have a JSON string, it should be one of the best solution.

```js
var anyObject = [
  {
    "Attr": [
      {
        "power": { "p1": "str", "t3": "str" },
        "light": [
          {"test": "str"},
          {"test2": [ { "t4": "str" }]}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Attr1": [
      {
        "power1": { "p2": "str", "t5": "str" },
        "light1": [
          { "test3": "str" },
          { "test_x": [
              { "t_x": "str" },
              { "t_y": [
                  { "t_y1": "str" }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

function getKeys(obj, str) {
let resultArr = [];
 JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj), (key, val) => {
  if(val === str) { resultArr.push(key) }
  return val;
 } )
return resultArr;
}

console.log(getKeys(anyObject, 'str'))
```

This is not case specific, you can have all the keys if you pass another callback in `JSON.parse` and also can transform the object using this (returning transformed value instead the actual value)

And if you want to use lodash to iterate the object recursively, then you can use 
`_.cloneDeepWith` for iterating the object recursively.

Here is a Working example:

```js
let anyObject = [
  {
    "Attr": [
      {
        "power": { "p1": "str", "t3": "str" },
        "light": [
          {"test": "str"},
          {"test2": [ { "t4": "str" }]}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Attr1": [
      {
        "power1": { "p2": "str", "t5": "str" },
        "light1": [
          { "test3": "str" },
          { "test_x": [
              { "t_x": "str" },
              { "t_y": [
                  { "t_y1": "str" }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

function getKeys(obj, str) {
  let resultArr = [];
  _.cloneDeepWith(obj, (value, key) => { value === 'str' && resultArr.push(key)});
  return resultArr;
}

console.log(getKeys(anyObject, 'str'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you are looking for something like this perhaps:

```js
var testArr = [{"Attr":[{"power":{"p1":"str","t3":"str"},"light":[{"test":"str"},{"test2":[{"t4":"str"}]}]}]},{"Attr1":[{"power1":{"p2":"str","t5":"str"},"light1":[{"test3":"str"},{"test_x":[{"t_x":"str"},{"t_y":[{"t_y1":"str"}]}]}]}]}];


var strFind = (arr, accumulator = []) => {
  arr.forEach(obj => {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if (value === "str") accumulator.push(key);
      if (Array.isArray(value)) strFind(value, accumulator);
      if (key.includes("power")) {
        Object.entries(value).forEach(([cKey, cValue]) => {
          if (cValue === "str") accumulator.push(cKey);
        })
      }
    });
  })
  return accumulator;
}

console.log(strFind(testArr));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another possibility, exploiting the naturally recursive nature of `JSON.stringify`:

```js
const input = [{"Attr":[{"power":{"p1":"str","t3":"str"},"light":[{"test":"str"},{"test2":[{"t4":"str"}]}]}]},{"Attr1":[{"power1":{"p2":"str","t5":"str"},"light1":[{"test3":"str"},{"test_x":[{"t_x":"str"},{"t_y":[{"t_y1":"str"}]}]}]}]}];

const output = [];
JSON.stringify(input, (key, val) => {
  if (val === 'str') output.push(key);
  return val;
});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var array = [];
function searchForStringInJsonRecursive (jsonData, str) {
    for(var i in jsonData) {
        // If the element is an Array or nested object continue to search
        if (typeof jsonData[i] === 'object') {
            searchForStringInJsonRecursive(jsonData[i], str);
        }
        // If the element is not an Object and matches str add the it to the array
        else if (jsonData[i] === str) {
            array.push(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming your json is in a variable called `data` you can call the function like this:
`searchForStringInJsonRecursive(data, 'str');`
`array` will then contain all the keys which content matched `'str'`

Answer (score 0):

Another try using `JSON.stringify` and string parsing:

```
const result = JSON.stringify(data)
  .match(/"[^"]+":"str"/g) // get all "xxx":"str" pairs
  .map(r => r.substring(1, r.indexOf(':') - 1)); // pick out all "xxx"

console.log(result);
// ["p1", "t3", "test", "t4", "p2", "t5", "test3", "t_x", "t_y1"]
```

Comment: Will this work if any keyor value contains ` :"str"`

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee You are right, the procedure should be tweaked to handle keys containing ':str'

Comment: If you're going to use a regular expression, `.map` is unnecessary, use lookahead instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using `lodash`:

```js
var testArr = [{"Attr":[{"power":{"p1":"str","t3":"str"},"light":[{"test":"str"},{"test2":[{"t4":"str"}]}]}]},{"Attr1":[{"power1":{"p2":"str","t5":"str"},"light1":[{"test3":"str"},{"test_x":[{"t_x":"str"},{"t_y":[{"t_y1":"str"}]}]}]}]}];

var findStr = function(o) {
  return _(o)
   .map(function(v, k) {
       return v === 'str'
           ? k
           : _.isObject(v) ? findStr(v) : null;
   })
   .compact()
        .flatten()
   .value();
};

console.log(findStr(testArr));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done it... I have used `lodash`. My code as following:

```js
var arrayData = [];
var teatData = [
  {
    "Attr": [
      {
        "power": { "p1": "str", "t3": "str" },
        "light": [
          {"test": "str"},
          {"test2": [ { "t4": "str" }]}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Attr1": [
      {
        "power1": { "p2": "str", "t5": "str" },
        "light1": [
          { "test3": "str" },
          { "test_x": [
              { "t_x": "str" },
              { "t_y": [
                  { "t_y1": "str" }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

function getKeyArray(data, arrayData) {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      _.forEach(data, (obj, key) => {
        this.getKeyArray(obj, arrayData);
      });
    } else if (_.isPlainObject(data)) {
      _.forEach(data, (obj, key) => {   
        if (obj === "str") {
          arrayData.push(key);
        } else if (Array.isArray(obj) || _.isPlainObject(obj)) {
          this.getKeyArray(obj, arrayData);
        }
      });
    }
  }
  
  getKeyArray(teatData, arrayData);
  
  console.log(arrayData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```